# "Новое счастье"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Честно говоря, меня коробит от пожелания на Новый год "нового счастья" (а еще, прозвучавшее в "Иронии судьбы" "с новым здоровьем"). Как счастье или здоровье может быть новым или старым? Оно или есть, или его нет))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здоровье - более или менее фиксированное понятие. Когда все в организме функционирует хорошо. А вот счастье - разнообразно. Может, у меня было счастье в работе, а будет - в семье (как предполагалось в "Иронии").

А помните, сколько определений счастья собрал Магнус Федорович Редькин (из "Понедельника...")! Хватит не только на каждый год, но и на каждую неделю!

Comment: Лишь бы счастья побольше!

Answer (score 2):

В чем вопрос?
С лингвистических позиций не вижу ничего противозаконого в определении "новое" для счастья, как и вообще для чего-либо. Для здоровья - тоже.
А уж стоит ли использовать такое пожелание - это, наверное, не сюда.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, "Ирония судьбы" фильм иронический. Так что не воспринимайте все так уж трагически. Считайте, что пожелание "нового здоровья" - это ирония по поводу пожелания "нового счастья".)))

Answer (score 0):

Ну, пожелание обычно звучит так : "С новым годом! С новым счастьем!" Может быть, имеется ввиду просто пожелание в новом году изменений в лучшую сторону. А здоровья ещё могут пожелать большого:-))